# audio sink buffer status update much slower, when repeated key is pressed to the edge of YT home page

Tags: cobalt

Compared with certified platform, YT home page in Cobalt updates audio sink status much slower when repeated key arrives the edge (about one second), is it a proper behavior?

> [cobalt]>[18880:6444373109:[CBT][WEBAUD][ERROR]:PlaybackLoop(224)] *#*buffer status, total/offset/playing/eos: 1024/1024/1/0
>
> [cobalt]>[18880:6445375301:[CBT][WEBAUD][ERROR]:PlaybackLoop(224)] *#*buffer status, total/offset/playing/eos: 1024/2048/1/0
>
> [cobalt]>[18880:6446382843:[CBT][WEBAUD][ERROR]:PlaybackLoop(224)] *#*buffer status, total/offset/playing/eos: 1024/1024/1/0

Comment: Are you running Cobalt on Linux? Can you provide the steps so that we can reproduce? Can you explain the logs that you attached? Updating audio sink status in 1s is not a normal behavior.

Comment: Yes, Cobalt RC11 runs on Linux/ARM.

Reproduce step, 1. launch YouTube Home Page. 2. navigate to the right edge. 3. press the right key on RC.

The log shows the interval of updating playing status is about one second, when doing SbAudioSinkUpdateSourceStatusFunc in a loop.

Moreover, the frequency seems to be normal as we do not navigate to the edge.

Comment: Hi Ceri, if you still experience this, can you please report this as an issue into Cobalt's tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=181120&template=699202. Thanks!